How can I move the caption for a specific plot closer to the plot in an HTML produced from an RMarkdown file?
Assume I have two plots (see example below). I want to move the caption for fig-one closer to the plot without that having any effect on the caption placement of fig-two.
I have seen that chunk options (https://yihui.org/knitr/options/) include out.extra, which looks useful but I haven't been able to make it work.
Any ideas?
---
output:
  bookdown::html_document2:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    fig_caption: true
    number_sections: false
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)

library(ggplot2)
```

# My nice plot 1

TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT 
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT 
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT 

```{r fig-one, fig.cap = "A really cool figure one."}
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point()
```

TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT 
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT 
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT 

# My nice plot 2

```{r fig-two, fig.cap = "A really cool figure two."}
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width)) +
  geom_point()
```

TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT 
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT 
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT 



Have you tried fig.align = ?

You can set a negative bottom-margin through out.extra for fig-one:
```{r fig-one, fig.cap = "A really cool figure one.", out.extra='style="margin-bottom: -20px;"'}
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point()
```

